server middleware Issues in production
am having problem with my server middle which is used to verifyToken, I am working with a MERN stack, everything works fine in development, but i get a 401 response from my server (which i am certain is coming from my middleware) when ever i try to make any request to my server in production.
I have tried everything possible but nothing seem to work, currently I have deployed only the server/backend while the frontend is still in development.  here is link to github repo , this is my server baseURL , I have also tried changing the backend/api endpoint, i have tried using other other hosting services but i keep getting the same issue. I am guessing the middleware.js verify's my token while in development but returns false while in production, i even change the token severally
